# Taskbar toolbar in C# for win7

Tags: c#, windows-7, toolbar, taskbar

Just a quick, hopefully very easy question. I wish to make a toolbar to place on the task bar (a common example of this is the language bar), the toolbar itself just has to display time until next bus.

My question comes in how I can do this, I can seem to find no information on how to create a taskbar toolbar. I'll be writing in C# and will be using windows 7. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To interop with taskbars you need to use native windows api. You can check msdn and read about windows api and use PInvoke to call correct windows methods or you can use library written in c# to wrap that common windows api. You can find such library at http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack.